# Having trouble installing rgdal and gdal on Centos

Tags: r, centos, gis, gdal, rgdal

I had a hell of a time getting gdal installed today, even though I've been able to do it successfully in the past. I finally got it working, so if you're reading this I hope I can save you some time.

If you are running into issues like:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

or

```
ogr_sfcgal.h:34:34: fatal error: SFCGAL/capi/sfcgal_c.h: No such file or directory
```

or you're stuck on the yum rpm of gdal that's at 1.11, then I hope the answer below helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have the dependencies installed, like SFCGAL:

```
sudo yum install SFCGAL -y
```

You might come across others with errors similar to the one above for SFCGAL. I'll leave it up to you to track them down and install them via yum.

A recent RPM of gdal isn't available via yum, so you will have to install from source. What often happens with installing gdal, it seems to me, is that a user will install to /usr/local/bin rather than /usr/bin, which is where rgdal seems to look. This means you need to install to /usr/bin. But how can you do this without an RPM? You will install from source.

It's simple. Download a >2.0 version of gdal here: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource

And run the following:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

After this, you might get an error like

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

You need to updated your shared library links. You can do this with:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

I hope this is helpful and that I saved you some time. I'm not an expert, so this might not be perfect advice. I wish you luck.

Comment: If you're having trouble due to an error like this:
    ```checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ is available fur running:... ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.```

Then set the env var GDAL_DATA to /usr/share/gdal

Answer (score 0):

I found that the yum installation of SFCGAL was always missing the header file.

Instead I removed SFCGAL then executed the gdal build/install steps.

```
sudo yum erase SFCGAL
```

After gdal was built and installed, I reinstalled SFCGAL

```
sudo yum install SFCGAL
```